# Mysql log confusion

Tags: debian, mysql

I have installed a standard installation of mysql on Debian Wheezy and I am confused as to where the logs are supposed to be logged. In my `/var/log/` directory, there are files `mysql.log` which are empty. All logging goes to `daemon.log` and `syslog`. To add to the confusion, `show variables like '%log%';` shows other logs still (My datadir is `/srv/mysql`) :

```
| general_log                             | OFF                               |
| general_log_file                        | /srv/mysql/mysql-systems.log      |
| slow_query_log                          | OFF                               |
| slow_query_log_file                     | /srv/mysql/mysql-systems-slow.log |
```

I like to keep my logs clean and organized. What would be the best way to log mysql. Should I change it on the `mysql` level, or in `rsyslog`. BTW, is there any standard for logs similar to [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mysql `general_log` logs **all** queries made to the mysql server and by default is disabled. 
The slow log will log any queries that have "especially long duration" (defaults to 2 minutes). Again this defaults to being disabled.

The default location for `mysqld_safe` to log is set by: `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf`, which defaults to syslog. You can either filter the results 
out to a separate file with your rsyslog config, or you can edit your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` 
file, and set a log location for errors with:

```
 log_error = /var/log/mysql.log
```